# O2 sensor location for 1990 pickup 4x4 3.0L

Tags: o2-sensor

I'm trying to locate the oxygen sensor on my 1990 Toyota pickup SR5 4x4 w/3.0L. I bought the truck from a kid who had the knock sensor wire rigged into the harness plug for the o2. I fixed the knock sensor by bypassing it. Does my truck have an O2 sensor? The new o2 sensor I bought has a pig tail about 16 inches long. Bosch part number 15711. I read somewhere that only Canada made trucks have these. How do I know where it was built? Help please

Answer (score 1):

The oxygen sensor is bolted to the exhaust pipe just ahead of the catalytic converter. This is under the truck below the drivers seat.

The first character of the VIN number denotes the country of origin.

J= Japan
 2= Canada
 3= Mexico
 4 & 5= USA